# Can't get input value from laravel contoller

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, laravel-5.6

I update input with id='total' with event onchange. When I fill quantity input,  the input total is updated with correct value  but when i try to get the value from controller, it returns null. Any idea? Thanks

This is the code:

```
    <div class="form-group" >
        <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity" onchange="updateInput(this.value)"  >
    </div>
</td>
<td align="center">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled >
    </div>
</td>
```

And this is function onchange

```
function updateInput(x)
{
    var price=parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').value);                  
    document.getElementById('total').value=parseFloat(x)*price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, just removed disabled attribute and it works.